# Issue with IE10 and legacy site, Compatibility mode (Browser mode rather then Document mode)

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility, internet-explorer-10

I have a Legacy site that has an iframe in the page to run a JavaScript powered customer details update form.

if this form is used in IE versions less than 10 it works correctly, in IE10 it defaults to Browser Mode: IE10 and Document Mode:Quirks

I need to be able to force just this page and/or the embedded iframe to Browser Mode: IE10 Compat View and Document Mode: IE5 quirks

I could rebuild the entire update form but there is so much functionality and the entire legacy site should be (fingers crossed) replaced in about 3 - 5 months removing the issue.  so until then I need a band-aid fix.

I have tried many meta compatibility tags but they only seem to effect the document mode.  I need this to stay as Quirks or IE5 quirks otherwise other portions of the site get messed up.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Hi Graham I have also facing a similiar issue, did you resolve it?. if so how?